# Laravel controller with modal bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I use Laravel Framework 5.4 and i need pass parameters from one button that open one Modal that receiving this parameters in myController and return data to myModal, somebody help me?

page1.blade.php

This button open my searchmodal.blade.php with jquery, it's Right my href to       call myController?

```
<a href="{{url('myController@search')}}" class="btn btn-success btnsearch">Search</a>
```

jquery

```
    $('.btnsearch').click(function(e){
               $("#searchmodal").modal('show');
     })
```

myController need this parameters and return variables to get in Modal.

myController.php

```
public function search(parameter1){

  $customers = Customer::find(parameter1);

  //return my modal or page1?
   return view('searchmodal', compact('customers'));
}
```

mymodal.blade.php, how do i get the customers variable from myController?

```
<div class="modal fade searchmodal" id="searchmodal"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="searchmodal" role="dialog">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you 're using blade templates, you can use [@foreach loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops)

Example:

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    <p>This is customer {{ $customer->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: show me Undefined variable: customers, how i do pass to model, it's right my return view?

Comment: `return view('searchmodal', compact('customers'));` should do it

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understood from your question: You have a button that opens up a modal with a search form and you need to pass the parameters to your controller which would return the results.

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Search</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="GET" action={{ route('your.search.route') }}>
              <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" />
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="search" />
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to perform the search in your controller

```
public function search(Request $request){
  // request object holds all the data you submitted through form
  $keyword = $request->search;

  // you can implement your search logic according to your need
  $customers = Customer::where('field_name', 'LIKE', $keyword . '%')->get();

  return view('searchmodal', ['customers' => $customers]);
}
```

In your view you can access the customer data

```
@foreach ($customers as $customer)
    <p>This is customer {{ $customer->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

You might have to change it as per your need but you should get the idea.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It's inverse! I need get data from controller in my Modal.

Comment: so you open the modal and fetch data from controller and show it in the modal?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not explain better

Comment: then why don't you ajax to fetch the data from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Controller

```
public function search(parameter1){
  $customers = Customer::find(parameter1);
  //return my modal or page1?
   return view('searchmodal', array('customers'=>$customers));
}
```

In the views you can access the `$customers` variable